# Delete all chrome account info from a single device

Tags: google-chrome

I logged into chrome at a device that isn't mine, and all my passwords synced to the device. Now, I don't have access to that device, and forgot to wipe out everything. Is there a way to make it wipe out automatically the next time it syncs, or do I need to change all my passwords?

Answer (score 1):

> You can remove your account from any device, even if you don't have that device in front of you. To sign out of any device, [check your "Recently used devices"](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity) and remove your account from any of them.

Refer to this page for details: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2390059

I don't think there is any way for you to remotely delete local data from Chrome but you should change your passwords anyway (as they may have copied them already). But remove the device before updating your passwords (other than your Google account's which I recommend changing immediately).

More information from the link:

## Sign out of Chrome

> When you sign out, your data will stop syncing to your Google Account. By default, the data you create while signed in will remain on the device. After you sign out, new data and changes you make in Chrome won't sync.
>
> **Sign out remotely** You can remove your account from any device, even if you don't have that device in front of you. To sign out of any device, check your "Recently used devices" and remove your account from any of them.
>
> **Sign out on a computer** Open Chrome.
>   At the top right, click More More and then Settings.
>   At the top, under "People," click Sign out.
>   Confirm by clicking Sign out.
>
> **Sign out on an Android device, iPhone or iPad**
>
> 1. Open the Chrome app.
> 2. At the top right, tap More More.
> 3. Tap Settings.
> 4. Tap your name.
> 5. Tap Sign out of Chrome.

## Remove someone from Chrome

> **On a computer** Multiple people can use Chrome on the same computer using multiple "Chrome profiles." After you remove someone from Chrome, their Chrome data is erased from the device.
>
> 1. Open Chrome.
> 2. At the top right, click the button with your name or People People.
> 3. Click Manage people.
> 4. Point to the person you want to remove.
> 5. At the top right of the person, click More More and then Remove This Person.
> 6. Confirm by clicking Remove This Person.
>
> **On an Android device, iPhone or iPad** There is only one user profile for Chrome on your device, and it can't be deleted.
>   To remove your data on your device, clear your browsing data.

Comment: You might consider adding further quoted reference from the content of the links you provided in case the links ever go bad, the content will still be on the answer.